# Why does this div drop down when InnterHtml is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div of thumbs and was wanting to change the innerHtml on click; however, whenever I insert something into them, they drop down and I am wanting them to remain in line.

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtDzs/

For example, if I wanted to add "something" to the boogie div in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <title>TITLE</title>
      <style>
         .thumbContainer {
            width: 200px;
         }
         .thumb {
            width: 95px;
            height: 95px;
            background-color: blue;
            display: inline-block;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
      <div>
         <div class="thumbContainer">
            <div id="boogie" class="thumb"></div>
            <div class="thumb"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="thumbContainer">
            <div class="thumb"></div>
            <div class="thumb"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="thumbContainer">
            <div class="thumb"></div>
            <div class="thumb"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="thumbContainer">
            <div class="thumb"></div>
            <div class="thumb"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="thumbContainer">
            <div class="thumb"></div>
            <div class="thumb"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script>
         (function() {
            $(".thumb").bind("click", function() {
               $("#boogie").html("something");
            });
         })();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason using `display: inline-block` is causing this problem...

There are two simple solutions:

**Overflow: hidden**

You can add this line to your class:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Here's the working [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jtDzs/10/)

---

**Float: left**

You can also start using floating to the left instead of display: inline-block and add the wanted margin.

```
// display: inline-block
float: left
margin: 2.5px;
```

Here's the working [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jtDzs/6/)

P.S I guessed you're trying to make this kind of behaviour to every div so I allowed myself to change the html changing command to:

```
$(this).html("something");
```

You can change this if you want

Comment: Edited and added a simpler solution using overflow: hidden

Answer (score 2):

```
     .thumb {
        color: white;
        width: 95px;
        height: 95px;
        margin: 2.5px;
        background-color: blue;
        float: left;
     }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtDzs/9/

Answer (score 0):

```
         (function() {
            $(".thumb").on("click", function() {
             $(this).("something");
           });
          })();
```

CSS is

```
     .thumb {
     color: white;
        width: 95px;
        height: 95px;
        background-color: blue;
        display: inline-block;
         float: left;
         margin: 2px;
     }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jtDzs/7/)

Hope it helps

Comment: did you try your demo?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand please try now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".thumb").on("click", function() {
               $(this).append("something");
            });
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/jtDzs/3/)

Comment: That doesn't work on Chrome or Firefox, and it changes the code, but not in a good way (click it multiple times).

Answer (score 0):

```
 (function() {
        $(".thumb").html("&nbsp;");
        $(".thumb").bind("click", function() {
           $("#boogie").html("something");
        });
     })();


.thumbContainer {
        width: 200px;
        height:100px;
     }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtDzs/11/

Comment: Using JS to insert "&nbsp;" to every cell is too farfetched

Comment: @Itay hmmm, I think it is better than messing with the layout using float when inline-block already works in my opinion and I don't think it is farfetched, JS is used to load pages in layouts, a blank space is nothing!, don't down vote unless and until my answer is wrong!

Comment: I believe that solving problems, that can be easily solved with basic CSS, with JavaScript is not a wise choice. Especially when you're not really solving the problem, just bypassing it. I don't think it's a good idea and that's why I've down voted. Nothing personal of course (!).

Comment: @italy You should explain a real downside, not just say you should use css instead,  if the answer works there's no reason to down vote

Comment: @JuanMendes : Instead of fixing a CSS rendering problem with JS, it's better to fix it with CSS so there's no problem at all. Don't you think? Anyway, I understand your point with the downvote but I can't cancel it because more than 7 hours have past, unless an edit will be made